# Spring Boot and Servlet Filter invocation

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot for my application. Due to a particular need, I have my own ***Servlet*** class that extends from the Spring ***DispatcherServlet***. (And I am pretty sure that I won't be the first one that is doing this.)

Everything worked fine until I tried adding authentication/authorization. I setup the authentication/authorization as shown here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest/security

I use the ***@PreAuthorize*** annotations on my REST controller methods to restrict access based on the type of operation such as GET/POST.

I get the error: **"AuthenticationObject not found in SecurityContextHolder"** when I try to POST something. What I did next was compare my application and a working Spring Boot Security example (as in the example above) by stepping through it to see what is happening. I discovered that in the working example, before the ***doService*** method of the DispatcherServlet is being invoked, filters such as BasicAuthenticationFilter and others come into the picture. I don't see these filters getting invoked in my application.

Due to the filters not being invoked I don't see the user information or the session-id in the request object at all in my application. I do see that in the working example though. Moreover, I see that in the working example, the request and response objects gets wrapped in a ***SecurityContextHolder*** Wrapper from the filter. Since filters don't get invoked in my application, the request/response objects never get wrapped. I suspect that the above error is related to this.

I guess that since I have my own Servlet class that extends the Spring Servlet, it is in essence saying to Spring that I will take control from there. This also means that I will have to do everything that normally Spring does for me.

My questions are :

- At what point in Spring Boot do the filters get invoked and how do I achieve
  this in my application before the request reaches my custom Servlet?
- Do I have to inject them as Beans into my Main class ? And in what order 
  should they be invoked?

Thanks again,

Comment: Just for curiosity - what need made you extend `DispatcherServlet`? Spring is built in a way that most likely you should not need to do that.